# Remove consecutive special characters from a file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a large file where I need to remove multiple occurrences of consecutive `\"` from the file.

I have used `sed -e 's/\"//g'`, but this removes all occurrences of `"` from the file.

```
"TERM" : "\"I CONTINUE
```

becomes

```
TERM" : I CONTINUE
```

but what I want is

```
"TERM" : "I CONTINUE
```

Please suggest the correct sed command to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to backslash the backslash to prevent its special meaning (i.e. preventing the special meaning of the following character).

```
sed 's/\\"//g'
```